# Control Legend() to display specific datasets

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, plot, legend

I'm attempting to display 2 major datasets namely "Type2" (red squares) and "Type1" (blue circles) in the legend. Nevertheless, since my plot involves subgroups of "Type1" and "Type2" (A,B are subgroups of each), there are 4 items appearing in the legend. Please take a look at how my plots looks like with only "Type":
[Query on errorbar() added to stripplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57246281/query-on-errorbar-added-to-stripplot/57252549?noredirect=1#comment101255729_57252549)

The issue is legend() tends to display 4 items : red square, red square, blue circle, blue cricle, while I need solely two of them i.e. red square to represent Type1 and clue circle for Type2.

```
Figure1 = plt.figure('Scatter Plot')
Subplot1 = Figure1.add_subplot(1,1,1)

########## PLOT Type2 Data ##################
markers = ['s','s']
colors = ['r', 'r']
grouped = DataFrame.groupby('Type2')

for i,((g,d),m,c) in enumerate(zip(grouped,markers,colors)):
    x = np.random.normal(loc=i,scale=0.2,size=(len(d['Y2'],))) 
    G_object1, _ = Subplot1.errorbar(x, y=d['Y2'], yerr=d['SD2'], 
                  fmt=m, color=c, capsize=3)

XPos = list(range(len(grouped)))
Subplot1.set_xticks(XPos)
Subplot1.set_xticklabels([a for a in grouped.groups])

########## PLOT Type1 Data ##################
markers = ['o','o']
colors = ['b', 'b']
grouped = DataFrame.groupby('Type1')

for i,((g,d),m,c) in enumerate(zip(grouped,markers,colors)):
    x = np.random.normal(loc=i,scale=0.2,size=(len(d['Y1'],))) 
    G_object2,_ = Subplot1.errorbar(x, y=d['Y1'], yerr=d['SD1'], 
                  fmt=m, color=c, capsize=3)

Subplot1.legend(['Type1','Type2'], [G_object1,G_object2])
```

Any comments are highly appreciated. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: If the question relates to matplotlib you should add the tag to it.

Answer (score 0):

Access the graph objects from the axis, then pass them into a legend:

```
# do this separately for each graph
ax.errorbar(x,d['Y1'],yerr=d['Err1'], fmt=m, color=c, capsize=3)
ax.errorbar(x,d['Y2'],yerr=d['Err2'], fmt=m, color=c, capsize=3)

# pass line objects into a legend
ax.legend([x for x in ax.lines],['Type1','Type2'], fontsize=15, title_fontsize = 16, loc='upper left', shadow=True)
```

Comment: I've now updated the original code above to include what you noted. Yet I'm getting an error: "ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)". Could you take a quick look at the code again? Many thanks.

Comment: @Riccardo. You should not change the original code in your question, as that invalidates the answers. You can append an edit, or better yet, add another question if you need additional help.

Comment: Looks like my order was wrong. Graph objects first, then lines. Corrected @Riccardo

Comment: Updated to make it a bit easier

Comment: It's still not showing the legend properly. What I'm getting is a red square for Type1 (which is the case even by simply doing: ax.legend(['Type1','Type2']) anyway) and a "dash line" for Type2. I'm in fact expecting to get a "blue circle" for Type2, not a "dash". Any tips on this? Thanks @YaakovBressler

Comment: Give me a sample of your dataframe and I'll execute on my end @Riccardo

Comment: You may find the data structure at the top of the page here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57246281/query-on-errorbar-added-to-stripplot/57252549?noredirect=1#comment101255729_57252549

Comment: A boxplot might be what you're looking for: `df.boxplot(by='Type')`

Comment: I'm merely attempting to get the legend right. How come I should be moving away from the current chart type?

Comment: The goal of your visualization is similar to that of a boxplot. You can definitely try to figure out how to get the axis exactly how you'd like them with this plot. Notwithstanding, this Q would require some cleaning up + clarification.